# Set Microsoft Edge to not close while downloading?

Tags: windows-10, download, microsoft-edge, file-download

Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0 on Windows 10 build 10586 allows you to close it while it is downloading something, losing all progress on the download.  I noticed this while using Google's excellent Takeout service, which lets me download an old user's mbox and Drive contents before closing their account.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 ,and which version of Edge are in question?

Comment: I adjusted the question with the answers

Comment: Since this isn't a feature of Edge, and add-ons are not yet supported by Edge, you should use some other browser that does have this feature.

Comment: This may not be much of a consolation, but the folks in the Windows Insider program have been testing a version of Edge that prompts you not to close Edge while a download is still on going.  This feature should appear in July with the Anniversary Update to Windows 10